# Showing favourites unique to the user that is logged in

Tags: swift, database, firebase, snapshot

I want a user to favourite a song they like, and when they go onto their favourites they see the ones that they have favourited. At the moment it crashes when it goes on to the page.

```
  var _favs = database.child("favs").child("\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)")
```

however if i take out the child path from the database reference it works but shows all songs favourited by the user.

This is my function that calls all favourites

```
func getAllFavourite(handler: @escaping (_ fav: [AlbumModel]) ->() ) {
    var favsArray = [AlbumModel]()
    favs.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (favSnapshot) in
        guard let favSnapshot = favSnapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {return}

        for favs in favSnapshot {
            let title = favs.childSnapshot(forPath: "title").value as! String
            let songId = favs.childSnapshot(forPath: "storeId").value as! String
            let artist = favs.childSnapshot(forPath: "artist").value as! String
            let senderId = favs.childSnapshot(forPath: "senderId").value as! String
            let fav = AlbumModel(artist: artist, senderId: senderId, title: title, storeId: songId)
            favsArray.append(fav)
        }

        handler(favsArray)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your database looking like this

```
{
    "favs": {
        "<user-id>":{
            "title":"some title",
            "storeid":"id",
            "artist":"artist name",
            "senderId":".."
        }
    }
}
```

with the path you access to that Snapshot (Dictionary), think as JsonObject

**/favs/** - you get a snapshot where *child.key =*  and *child.value = {"title:"...}*

**/favs/user-id/** - you get a snapshot where *child.key = "title"* and *child.value = ".."*, second *child.key = "storeid"* and *child.value = ".."*

So be sure when you get access to *favs/* you get the child object, but not an one-element array.

Also instead of calling *childSnapshot*, I will recommend using this:

```
if let value = snap.value as? [String:Any] {
    // do you stuff here
    let title = value["title"] as? String ?? "default title"
}
```